# Hadoop PIG ouput is not split in mutliple files with PARALLEL operator

Tags: hadoop, parallel-processing, apache-pig, reducers

Looks like I'm missing something. Number of reducers on my data creates that many number of files in HDFS, but my data is not split into multiple files. What I noticed is that if I do a `group by` on a key that is in sequential order it works fine, like the data below split nicely into two files based on the key:

```
1    hello
2    bla     
1    hi
2    works
2    end
```

But this data doesn't split:

```
1    hello
3    bla     
1    hi
3    works
3    end
```

The code that I used that works fine for one and not for the other is

```
InputData = LOAD 'above_data.txt';
GroupReq =  GROUP InputData BY $0 PARALLEL 2;
FinalOutput =   FOREACH GroupReq GENERATE flatten(InputData);
STORE FinalOutput INTO 'output/GroupReq' USING PigStorage ();
```

The above code creates two output part files but in first input it splits the data nicely and put the key `1` in `part-r-00000` and key `2` in `part-r-00001`. But for the second input it creates two part files but all the data ends up in `part-r-00000`. What is it I'm missing, what can I do to force the data to split in to multiple output files based on the unique keys?

Note: for the second input if I use `PARALLEL 3` (3 reducers), it creates three part files and add all the data for key `1` in `part-0` and all the data for key `3` in `part-3` file. I found this behavior strange. BTW I'm using Cloudera CDH3B4.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the number of the reducer that a key goes to is determined as `hash(key) % reducersCount`. If the key is an integer, `hash(key) == key`. When you have more data, they will be distributed more or less evenly, so you shouldn't worry about it.